# Find address of matching range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the image below, I am trying to find the address of all matching cells. That is, if OneSource (for example) is found in 3 rows (it will always be continuous rows), then I need to show address like F2:F4.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have created a formula which gives me the address of the first instance of the match but not the full range.

`=CELL("address",INDEX($F$2:$F$12,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$12,0),1))`

How do I get the full range address?

Comment: The thing is that `CELL()` returns a cell address. You will have  to do some string manipulation to get the range. Is the column F sorted?

Comment: In your actual data, is column F sorted?

Comment: @user11087823 - Now that I looked at my real data, yes it is sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the data is sorted, you will need two parts to your formula, the first part to get the address of the first cell, and a second part to get the address of the last cell. You already got the first part. For the second part, you can use a similar formula, but notice how `MATCH` is different:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($F$2:$F$16,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$16,0)))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX($F$2:$F$16,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$16,1)))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I missed the simpler `MATCH` solution for the second part earlier. In case you are still interested in the previous array formula, it's the following:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($F$2:$F$16,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$16,0)))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX($F$2:$F$16,MAX(IF($F$2:$F$16=A2,ROW($F$2:$F$16)-1))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try to use the max method but wasn't getting the desired result as I didn't make it an array formula. Now it works but I still don't understand how array formula worked in this case

Comment: If the data is actually sorted then i believe MATCH can easily return the last row without an array formula. The sample data in the question wan't sorted.

Comment: @user11087823 if it was not sorted, then the ranges would not be accurate. Saying `A` is in range `F2:F7` while there is a `B` at `F3` is problematic IMO.

Comment: Oh, being sorted, I meant more like all the similar elements being grouped together; which sorting ensures. The actual order of each group of elements is not relevant.

Comment: a) that's **grouping** not **sorting**. Sorting would mean that *ThreeSource* came before *TwoSource* in an ascending sort where *OneSource* came before both. b) *'... gets the row number of the last occurrence'* is wrong. It gets the **cell* containing the last occurrence. It's only the `MAX(IF($F$2:$F$16=A2,ROW($F$2:$F$16)-1))` part that gets the row number.

Comment: @user11087823 Ah now I get you meant earlier, and yes you are correct on that. I still maintain my point on the sorting however, since that's the easiest way to ensure data is grouped (if the data is sorted, it has to be grouped, while it is much harder to ensure data is grouped).

Comment: See my response below to achieve the same result on truly sorted data.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted data allows you to take advantage of binary lookup matches. These are simple to write and functionally faster than a non-sorted lookup.

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(A2, E:E, 0), 5, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A2&" ", E:E), 5, 4)
```

The first address is the conventional exact match. The second address is achieved through looking for the last one in a sorted list by appending a suffix space character.

Since you are dealing with a known column, I've thrown out the CELL function in favor of the ADDRESS constructor.

[image]

This method of binary match on sorted data will produce unreliable results (results, not errors, that may or may not be correct) on unsorted data.

Comment: Thanks. This works too (however I will use the accepted answer as I am not very sure about data being sorted). Could you please explain how the second part works `MATCH(A2&" "`?

Comment: [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) What's the difference between the start and stop MATCH formulas above?

Comment: @asd123 Adding a space is like telling `MATCH` to look for something slightly greater than `A2`, which will usually result in the last match of `A2` in that range.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interesting to use VBA Change Event you can try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LastrowA As Long, LastrowF As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim Source As String, strAddress As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Set the sheet which you will use
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        'Find Last rows for Column A & F
        LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastrowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Chek if the changes intersect our ranges

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A", "F:F")) Is Nothing Then

        For i = 2 To LastrowA

            Source = ws.Range("A" & i).Value

            Application.EnableEvents = False
                'Count Times
                ws.Range("B" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("F2:F" & LastrowF), Source)

                strAddress = ""
                'Import Address
                For y = 2 To LastrowF
                    If ws.Range("F" & y).Value = Source Then
                        If strAddress = "" Then
                            strAddress = ws.Range("F" & y).Address
                        Else
                            strAddress = strAddress & "," & ws.Range("F" & y).Address
                        End If
                    End If
                Next y

                ws.Range("C" & i).Value = strAddress

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]